# Which part of the Router code provides the TypeError: requires Middleware function but got a Object

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

In this fictive project I am trying to set up the Routing structure. Although I used module.exports in both files, running a test still gives me the following error:

**TypeError: Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a Object**

My Code:

Minions.js

```
const minionsRouter = require('express').Router();

module.exports = minionsRouter;

const {
    getAllFromDatabase,
    addToDatabase,
    getFromDatabaseById,
    updateInstanceInDatabase,
    deleteFromDatabasebyId,
} = require('./db.js');

minionsRouter.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    const minionsArray = getAllFromDatabase('minions');

    if (minionsArray) {
        res.status(200).send(minionsArray);
    } else {
        res.status(404).send();
    }
});
```

API.js

```
const express = require('express');
const apiRouter = express.Router();

const minionsRouter = require('./minions');
const ideasRouter = require('./ideas');
const meetingsRouter = require('./meetings');

apiRouter.use('/minions', minionsRouter);
apiRouter.use('/ideas', ideasRouter);
apiRouter.use('/meetings', meetingsRouter);


module.exports = apiRouter;
```

Server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

module.exports = app;

/* Do not change the following line! It is required for testing and allowing
*  the frontend application to interact as planned with the api server
*/
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4001;

// Add middleware for handling CORS requests from index.html
const cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors());

// Add middleware for parsing request bodies here:
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Mount your existing apiRouter below at the '/api' path.
const apiRouter = require('./server/api');
app.use('/api', apiRouter);


// This conditional is here for testing purposes:
if (!module.parent) { 
  // Add your code to start the server listening at PORT below:
  app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server is listening on port ${PORT}`)
  })
};
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Do `ideas.js` and `meetings.js` have the same structure as `minions.js`, with `module.exports = someRouter;`? The code you showed looks fine

Comment: Yes, I haven’t got to that part of the project yet. My goal was just to check it minions.js ran into any errors before proceeding.

Comment: So, do you still get the error when you comment these two lines? `apiRouter.use('/ideas', ideasRouter); apiRouter.use('/meetings', meetingsRouter);`

Comment: That works! So to conclude, if any router.use is invoked, it should already have some code to rely on. 
Is it me or does this error not really get to the point of what actually went wrong?

Comment: _"does this error not really get to the point of what actually went wrong"_ Well, it pointed me to the correct lines, so I guess it does :-) It's saying that you called `Router.use` with an Object as a parameter instead of a Function. _"if any router.use is invoked, it should already have some code to rely on"_ This is not specific to Express, any function could break or throw errors when you pass it parameters that it did not expect/does not know how to handle

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation. Still new to these concepts and they are quite tough to understand from time to time. Have a good one!